# Watching CD/DVD burning files on Windows

Tags: c++, logging, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I just want to log all files wrote to CD-ROM/DVD disks, and the source file (file which it's copied from) - and I cannot depend anyway from the burnning software.

It's to know every file copied from the computer to any removable media.

Comment: What operating system?  Which auditing tools for your OS have you already looked at, and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: Windows. I'm currently working with FileSystemWatcher API - but according to the MSDN docs, it doesn't work with CD/DVD drives.

Answer (score -1):

Without depending on the burning software, you can't reliably know this information.

Comment: I haven't any way to know what's the process/program which is burning the CD/DVD, and find what files have it openned? I don't know much about the burning process at Windows, but I think the burning software uses some kind of ISO filesystem image. So, may I find the image file anyway?

Comment: That's not really a programming question anymore.

Comment: May I have a programming way to detect burning software openning the ISO image file before start recording??

Comment: The `FileSystemWatcher` API might be able to note the creation of files with a .iso extension. But if you tell us *what you actually are trying to accomplish* we might be able to give you a more useful solution.